# Downloading Notes app notes without iCloud?

Tags: iphone, macos, ios, notes.app

Is there any way to get notes from the iOS 6 Notes app off of an iPhone without requiring an internet connection (or thus iCloud)?

iTunes Sync, which did Sync Notes on iOS 5 to Mail app on OS X Snow Leopard, no longer works for notes on iOS 6 and Mountain Lion.

Added: I found some commercial solutions as answered below.  Are there any free (built-in, open source or non-expiring) solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure that it's possible without an internet connection, but since notes are just a subset of IMAP, you should be able to use any IMAP e-mail account (e.g. Gmail) for that purpose after you add the account in Settings.app and enable Note Syncing. However, I can't think of a way to do it without *any* internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

There appear to be 4 commercial Mac OS applications that can read Notes from un-encrypted iTunes backup files, which does include iPhone 5 notes, even with iCloud disabled.  This [arstechnica article](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/10/hands-on-four-mac-apps-to-transfer-voicemail-other-files-from-your-iphone/) mentions PhoneView, iExplorer and 2 others.

After turning off local Backup encryption for an iPhone 5 in iTunes (FileVault is already turned on for the local User directory containing this backup anyway) and doing another Sync, iExplorer successfully read the notes from the Notes app, even completely offline, and with iCloud not turned on for this device.

Not low cost or free, but better than nothing.